# Why can't I browse to my WCF service in Windows Server 2012?

Tags: wcf, windows-server, windows-server-2012

On any other operating system, if I browse to my WCF service in the browser, I can see information about that service.  In Windows Server 2012, I get no information about the service, and it even acts as if there's nothing there at that address.  I can still access the service from a client, but I had to add a server feature just to make it work (.NET Framework 4.5 Features -> WCF Services -> HTTP Activation).

Browsing to the service is normally a quick way to make sure that the service is running, but it's a slight annoying that I no longer have this luxury.  Does anyone know how I can get Windows Server 2012 to show information about my service when I browse to it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your services' configuration or code modifies the default behavior to enable metadata to be published:

[How to: Publish Metadata for a Service Using a Configuration File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734765.aspx)